# confd peers are not reachable

Tags: coreos, etcd, confd

Running

```
confd -debug=true -verbose -onetime -node 172.17.0.61:4001 -confdir ./confd
```

gives me the following

```
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: WARNING Skipping confd config file.
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: NOTICE Starting confd
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: NOTICE etcd nodes set to http://172.17.0.61:4001
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: DEBUG Loading template resources from confdir ./confd
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: DEBUG Processing template resource confd/conf.d/test.toml
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: DEBUG Loading template resource from confd/conf.d/test.toml
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: DEBUG Retrieving keys from etcd
2014-08-08T10:57:25+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: DEBUG Key prefix set to /
2014-08-08T10:57:26+02:00 HAL75 confd[20762]: ERROR 501: All the given peers are not reachable (Tried to connect to each peer twice and failed) [0]
```

however if I do a curl request to the exact same server and key/value pair that the confd
template and conf have, I get the json response back from etcd correctly. Not sure, why confd is not working?

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Nope, eventually wrote a little utility in Go that queries etcd and then write the configuration file segment that I needed to update.

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure the `-addr` and `-bind-addr` on etcd.